# List index out of range, when i make the range 1 smaller it misses one item

Tags: python, list, indexing, pygame, tuples

I want to focus on the print_shape() function. Sincle tuples cannot be changed, i created a for loop to iterate every single tuple in the list "x_placement", which means in the range(1, len(x_placement) + 1).
However, when i tried to run the program i get the error message below that says "list index out of range" when the function is activated.

I tried range(1, len(x_placement)) instead (without + 1). It worked, but just created a shape without the last point (the last tuple in x_placement list).
How do i fix this?

````
import sys

WIDTH = 300
HEIGHT = 300

turn = 1

DARK_BLUE = (0, 0, 200)

horizontal_top_line = [0, 85, 300, 20]
horizontal_bottom_line = (0, 195, 300, 20)
vertical_left_line = (85, 0, 20, 300)
vertical_right_line = (195, 0, 20, 300)

x_placement = [(20, 30), (30, 20), (45, 40), (60, 20), (70, 30), (50, 45), (70, 60), (60, 70), (45, 50), (30, 70),
               (20, 60), (40, 45)]


def draw_board():
    pg.draw.rect(screen, DARK_BLUE, horizontal_top_line)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, DARK_BLUE, horizontal_bottom_line)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, DARK_BLUE, vertical_right_line)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, DARK_BLUE, vertical_left_line)


def check_square():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    if mouse[0] <= 90:
        x = 1
    elif 110 <= mouse[0] <= 190:
        x = 2
    elif 210 <= mouse[0] <= 290:
        x = 3

    if mouse[1] <= 90:
        y = 1
    elif 110 <= mouse[1] <= 190:
        y = 2
    elif 210 <= mouse[1] <= 290:
        y = 3

    return x, y


def print_shape(square, turn):
    if turn % 2 == 1:
        specific_x = []
        for n in range(1, len(x_placement) + 1):
            specific_x.append((x_placement[n][0] + (square[0] - 1) * 100, x_placement[n][1] + (square[1] - 1) * 100))
        pg.draw.polygon(screen, DARK_BLUE, specific_x)
    elif turn % 2 == 0:
        pass
    else:
        pass

    turn += 1


screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

game_over = False

while not game_over:

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            current_square = check_square()
            print_shape(current_square, turn)

    mouse = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    draw_board()
    pg.display.update()```

 File "C:/Users/idof/PycharmProjects/TickTacToe/game.py", line 73, in <module>
    print_shape(current_square, turn)
  File "C:/Users/idof/PycharmProjects/TickTacToe/game.py", line 51, in print_shape
    specific_x.append((x_placement[n][0] + (square[0] - 1) * 100, x_placement[n][1] + (square[1] - 1) * 100))
IndexError: list index out of range
````

Comment: start from 0, not 1.

Comment: Indices start with `0`. Shouldn't it be `for n in range(0, len(x_placement)):`? Are you sure it is missing the last and not the first element?

Comment: You can do `for item in x_placement: apecific_x.append(item...`, you don't need to use range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python list indices start at 0.

So in your code, specifically in your `def print_shape(square, turn)` function. Replace the for loop from this:

```
for n in range(1, len(x_placement) + 1):
```

To this:

```
for n in range(len(x_placement)):
```